# Upload PHP slim using FTP

Tags: php, ftp, slim

*See the solution below in the post*

---

My php slim urls works fine on my local.
But if i upload to using FTP to my online server, 
I get 404 error, 
any ideas why?

this is my route code:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '',
  'app_secret' => '',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
  ]);

$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
});

//get all
$app->post('/api/mykenteken', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($fb){
  $token = $request->getParam('token');

  try {
    $fb_response = $fb->get('/me', $token);
  } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo '{"error": {"text": "'.$e->getMessage().'"} }';
    exit;
  } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo '{"error": {"text": "'.$e->getMessage().'"} }';
    exit;
  }

  $id = $request->getParam('id');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM test where id = $id";

   try{
         // Get DB Object
         $db = new db();
         // Connect
         $db = $db->connect();
         $stmt = $db->query($sql);
         $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
         $db = null;
         echo json_encode($users);
     } catch(PDOException $e){
         return $response->withStatus(400)->write('{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}}');
     }
});
```

I uploaded my php slim files using fileZilla.
I am using composer on my local.

on my local i redirect my ip to localdev domain

**update**

my php code are in this path on my online server:

domain/public_html/beta/php

and this is folder structure of php folder:

[image]

.htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

---

**Soltion**

I got what is the issue:

I must looking into this folder: domain/public_html/beta/php/public
And not: domain/public_html

so

The link of the api must be is: http://www.domain.nl/beta/php/public/myapilink
And not: http://www.domain.nl/myapilink

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Hi Ben, I added some code

Comment: Sounds like you've missed a `.htaccess` file or similar. Is your online server using Apache?

Comment: Hi Phil, i update my post and add .htaccess code and folder structure. is this ok?

Comment: I got what was the problem here, see updated post

Answer (score 0):

404 is a server error, so the issue is that the file isn't available, not anything with your code. Check that after the file is uploaded it is set to be publicly readable. Even if the file is marked as such, you may need to check that the folder that contains it on the server is set to be publicly readable as well.

Looking at your code, two issues stick out. The first is that `$db = $db->connect();` needs some parameters specifying the database, username, and password (or other connection settings depending upon how your database is set up). I'm not sure how your PHP engine and database are setup, but looking at your code, it'll likely involve replacing:

```
$db = new db();
```

with something like:

```
$db = new PDO( "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password );
```

The second issue is that your code is highly-vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). To fix this, replace:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test where id = $id";
```

with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test where id = :id";
```

and:

```
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
```

with:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();
```

This process is called "using prepared statements". It will save you a lot of heartache!

Comment: Given OP's code has `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, I'd say they're using PDO, not MySQLi

Comment: `bindParam`, not `bind_param`

Comment: @Phil Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Hi ben, i update my post and add .htaccess code and folder structure. is this ok? because everyhting works ok on my local

Comment: @Momen That sounds right. Give it a try and report back the results.